# React Native Admob google mobile ads not working on real device, Rewarded ads working on Emulator but crashing on real device

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, admob, ads, google-mobile-ads

I am creating a react native app, In my Emulator google mobile ads (Rewarded testing ads) working very well. but when I test the app on my real device(Personal phone) then the rewarded Ads not work, it crashed the app, only banner ads working on real device.

What is the problem, could anyone please reply with a solution?

Need support on this issue, Thank you in advance

```
Here below is the code I am using for rewarded ads

    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { View, Button, Text, ScrollView, } from 'react-native'
    import { RewardedAd, RewardedAdEventType, TestIds } from 'react-native-google-mobile-ads';
    
    const adUnitId = __DEV__ ? TestIds.REWARDED : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917';
    
    const rewarded = RewardedAd.createForAdRequest(adUnitId, {
      requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
      keywords: ['fashion', 'clothing'],
    });
    
    const Testing = ({ navigation }) =>{
        const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
    
        useEffect(() => {
          const unsubscribeLoaded = rewarded.addAdEventListener(RewardedAdEventType.LOADED, () => {
            setLoaded(true);
            rewarded.show();
          });
          const unsubscribeEarned = rewarded.addAdEventListener(
            RewardedAdEventType.EARNED_REWARD,
            reward => {
              console.log('User earned reward of ', reward);
            },
          );
      
          // Start loading the rewarded ad straight away
          rewarded.load();
      
          // Unsubscribe from events on unmount
          return () => {
            unsubscribeLoaded();
            unsubscribeEarned();
          };
        }, []);
      
        return (
            <ScrollView>
            <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent : 'center',alignItems : 'center'}}>
            <Text> 
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
             </Text>
            <Button onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('First')} title='Next Screen'></Button>
               </View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
        
        }
        export default Testing;
```